# How do I prompt for booting Debian in GNOME or text mode?

Tags: boot, debian, gnome, gnome3, text-mode

Sometimes I would like to boot my laptop running Debian with GNOME 3 normally, however sometimes I would like to boot into text mode without having to manually stop the gdm3 service. Currently, I have to either manually stop gdm3 when the computer is booted or I have to boot into text mode and manually start the service.

How can I add an option (perhaps in the GRUB menu?) that will allow me to boot into a different mode if I choose?

Comment: A less invasive option is to just boot into Gnome3 and then hit Ctrl-Alt-F1, that will give you a text-based terminal (Ctrl-Alt-F7 to get back). The drawback is that gdm3 will still be running in the background.

Comment: @NZD I was aware of that but the goal of text mode is to eliminate the processing associated with gdm3.

Comment: Were you able to try changing the grub boot line or adding a new entry to the menu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an extra `menuentry` in /boot/grub/grub.cfg that copies your existing `menuentry` for Debian (the non-recovery one)

Change the line the begin with `linux` (e.g. `linux /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-29-generic root=/dev/sda1` ) and add a space and then the runlevel to the end.

The above line changed to boot runlevel 3 would be:
`linux /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-29-generic root=/dev/sda1 3`

You can also change the runlevel during bootup by hitting `e` at the grub screen to enter edit mode.
Once in edit mode, go to the end of the `linux` line, add a space and your runlevel then hit `F10` or `Control+x` to boot.

Comment: Modifying inittab is not the same as the grub modification above.

Comment: Just got around to trying this but it worked great. Thanks!